# 404 when redirected to redirect_uri with a state and code

Tags: python, django, redirect, callback, google-api

I am trying to build a django application that will use the YouTube Data API v3. 
Part of code in views.py

```
    YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly"
    YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
    YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"



FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(
    settings.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRETS_JSON,
    scope=YOUTUBE_READONLY_SCOPE)

FLOW.redirect_uri = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/"

@login_required
def index(request):
  storage = DjangoORMStorage(CredentialsModel, 'id', request.user, 'credential')
  credential = storage.get()
  if credential is None or credential.invalid == True:
```

I am being redirected to this.

[image]

After logging in. It redirects me to -

[image]

I am following this link from [google](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#flows).
I have all the values set in Google Cloud Platform as well.

Any sample code will be helpful.

Comment: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/"  <-- remove the / at the end and make sure you have that page in your project.

Comment: Do I need to create that page separately or this comes with the default Django auth? I am new to Django

Comment: I dont know Django,  I just know Google Oauth,  You need to have a page to respond to the token when its returned.